# Is there a tested bundle or a wrapper for symfony2-cassandra?

Tags: symfony, cassandra

I'm starting a project that requires me to use non relational databases, specifically cassandra with the symfony2 php framework, however I'm concerned if there is a tested wrapper or bundle for me to use.

I'm also new to the PHP world, but I have 10+ years of experience in C++. If I don't have a wrapper or a bundle, can I still use phpcassa or cpcl (cassandra php client library) together with symfony?

Thanks